# why i am receiving cant open file 'opencv_core2411d.obj'

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv, visual-studio-2012

I am tryin to use openCV-2.4.11 library in visual studio 2013, to do so i followed
[this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e_TQ9c3n_d8) and [this slideshare tutorial](http://de.slideshare.net/andredsm/apresentacao-36089830)

unfortunately, every time i run any C++ code even "Hello world", the compiler generates this error `Link: fatal error LINK1104: cant open file 'opencv_core2411d.obj'`

I also referred to some question in SO but they were not detailed or they discuss importing opencv library but in another IDE not visual studio.

**note**: the libs i used as input to the linker in the field 'Additional Dependencies':

```
opencv_calib3d2411d.lib
opencv_contrib2411d.lib
 opencv_core2411d.lib
opencv_features2d2411d.lib
opencv_flann2411d.lib
opencv_gpu2411d.lib
opencv_haartraining_engined.lib
opencv_highgui2411d.lib
opencv_imgproc2411d.lib
opencv_legacy2411d.lib
opencv_ml2411d.lib
opencv_nonfree2411d.lib
opencv_objdetect2411d.lib
opencv_photo2411d.lib
opencv_stitching2411d.lib
opencv_ts2411d.lib
opencv_video2411d.lib
opencv_videostab2411d.lib
```

and i am using win8

please provide steps to successfully import opecv2.4.11 into visula studio and let me know why i am receivin this error

Comment: Just a tip: what happened if you delete the space from the beginning of `opencv_core2411d.lib`? Is it working in release?

Comment: @Kornel i checked the linker->input: and i found that the above listed libs are added without leading spaces

Comment: It's quite interesting because VS shouldn't have to link any object file by itself. Are you sure you didn't swap the extensions? Don't you have another project with wrong settings?

Comment: what do u mean by wapping settings?? as i am new to VS and C-++ i have created some projects with settings in Debug and Release but i dont know whether or not they might affect any upcoming project!! so, yes maybe i have created projects with wrong settings, so what should i do know

Answer (score 0):

In my experience the linker error:

> Link: fatal error LINK1104: cant open file 'opencv_core2411d.obj'

usually means that the linker cannot find the file. This is generally because the linker properties are not correct.

Check the property page under linker->"Additional Library Directories" and make sure that it is filled in and the path is correct.

Depending on how you have the project setup you may have different settings for debug and release configurations.

Answer (score 0):

I was also having the same problem for quite a time and after searching everywhere in the internet i finally got the solution.
These input files are correct but you need to give the full path in Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies. i will show you how.

```
C:\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_calib3d2411d.lib
C:\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_contrib2411d.lib
C:\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_core2411d.lib
C:\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_features2d2411d.lib
C:\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_flann2411d.lib
C:\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_gpu2411d.lib
C:\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_highgui2411d.lib
C:\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_imgproc2411d.lib
C:\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_legacy2411d.lib
C:\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_ml2411d.lib
C:\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_objdetect2411d.lib
C:\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_ocl2411d.lib
C:\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_photo2411d.lib
C:\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_stitching2411d.lib
C:\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_superres2411d.lib
C:\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_ts2411d.lib

C:\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_video2411d.lib
C:\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_videostab2411d.lib
```

Also in Linker->General->Use Library Dependency Input, Click on yes
This should certainly help.